# How to stop git from making files non-executable on cygwin?

Tags: git, permissions, cygwin

I use git on Windows via cygwin and soon decided to use `filemode=false` (since otherwise I've got a lot of changes after the initial git clone). I'm definitely not interested in tracking permission at all, the only think I need is for some files to be executable. From time to time, I find that the `x` flag on some files gets lost and I strongly suppose it's because of git.

I'd be happy with a solution allowing to execute `chmod a+x ...` when needed.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I believe you want `git update-index --chmod=+x <file>`, followed by a commit.

Comment: I don't think it helps, since I'm using `filemode=false`, so I assume I have to do something after getting files out of git (as opposed to putting them in git). Something which applies whenever git changes or creates a file. Moreover, it should run automatically.

Comment: [The docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html#_configuration) specifically recommend this command for systems where filemode=false.  If I understand it correctly, that setting only applies to _automatic_ detection of permission changes.  Git still stores a filemode, which is the first column when you do a `git ls-tree HEAD`.  If it shows up as 644 instead of 755, then git won't set the executable bit when it writes that file.

Comment: I see I was misunderstanding `filemode=false`. Somehow I thought, it would disable storing the bits, but "the executable bit differences between the index and the working copy are ignored" instead.

Comment: Now I get it... it works, but of course not if I checkout an older version. This is something I should have done after the first commit of the executable file (not it's too late since I really don't want to rebase the whole history). It's not perfect, but it helps, thank you.

Comment: You might consider a [post checkout hook script](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_checkout) to take care of the older versions.

Comment: This would be easy and practical, but from the description I'm not sure if it always applies, e.g., after rebase. Does it? OTOH, I'm not going to do a lot of with the old commits, so together with the above it's probably sufficient.

Comment: I use the Cygwin version of git.  My co-workers use the "git bash" shell, which uses MSYS rather than Cygwin.  They *should* work happily together, but *.bat files that other people check in appear to be executable for them, but not for me.  I think that MSYS implicitly makes *.bat files executable when it creates them, but doesn't bother to preserve the executable bit when they're checked in; Cygwin doesn't do this.  (I run `chmod +x` and check them in when needed.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Did you try what Karl wrote? I think it should help.

Answer (score 6):

You should start with `git update-index --chmod=+x <file>`.

But this does not change your working copy, for that:

```
git checkout .
```

Answer (score 5):

I've met the same problem. 
git update-index --chomd=+x  doesn't work for me.

I use chmod +x , then commit, it works perfect.

Comment: Or use update-index, commit, check out the file again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this command worked:

```
git add --chmod=+x -- <file>
```

Commit after that (and push), done.

In Bitbucket pull request before:

[image: before]

After (just the one commit):

[image: after]

After (all changes):

[image]

The difference between git [update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) and [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) is explained in [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585812/what-is-the-difference-between-git-add-and-git-update-index).