# Is there an easy way to test Openshift Autoscaling?

Tags: django, openshift

I'm migrating a Django application to Redhat Openshift Online. The application is subject to spikes in demand, so I want to use the Openshift [Autoscaling functionality](https://blog.openshift.com/how-paas-auto-scaling-works-on-openshift/).

To test this, I use Apache JMeter to put a lot of load on the server, to see whether the new gears launch I expect. But I'm encountering bugs with the server scaling up, like my deployment scripts not working as expected, or migrations not occurring correctly on the database. Is there a more convenient way to test the auto-scaling than sending a bunch of requests at the server until haproxy launches a new gear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scale applications up or down using both the web console and the rhc command line tool.  You can read more about how to do it here: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/scaling.html#managing-application-scaling

Can you provide more details about what scripts/migrations are not working correctly on the newly created gears?  You can also feel free to send questions/issues to https://developers.openshift.com/contact.html

Comment: The deployment script was not executable - which was preventing the virtualenv requirements from being loaded, see [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713157/openshift-action-hooks-are-not-executable)