# /Fabric.framework/run: Permission denied

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, twitter-fabric

While running my App I am getting

> Path/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-hhrnpfyhpluwgwcdjsjkbeehwwqs/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/Script-C0EDB4D81B6759AC0067631D.sh: line 2: ./Fabric.framework/run: Permission denied

If any one faced the similar issue , please suggest me the way to fix this?

I am running in Xcode 7.0 , iOS 9

I have this in my plist

[image]

Any helps is appreciated!

**Edit :This solved my issue**:

**Step:1:** Sign up for Fabric [Here](https://fabric.io/sign_up)

**Step:2:** Follow the steps as mentioned in [this LINK](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/fabric/getting-started.html)
and add the key for fabric framework in info.plist and "Run Script" as [shown here](http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com/?utm_source=desktopapp&utm_medium=setup&utm_campaign=mac)

Comment: Create account in Fabric, create App and login through it. and then Run again..and Succeess

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077727/ios-xcode-5-crashlytics-error-shell-script-invocation-error-crashlytics-fr

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I faced this issue when I cloned a repo and Fabric binaries were already there (commited by other developer). The solution was to run this commands in project folder and after then the xcode build succeeded:

```
chmod +x Fabric.framework/run
chmod +x Fabric.framework/uploadDSYM
```

Answer (score 3):

Permission issue solved with **fabric 3.7.1 with cocoa pods**:

Installed Fabric with:

> pod 'Fabric'
>
> pod 'Crashlytics'

Now import below two headers in  "AppDelegate.h" class

```
  #import <Fabric/Fabric.h>     
  #import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

**Add below line**  in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions:

> [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];

Updated shell script with **pods root path** with fabric key which will generated while installing fabric signup in **build Phase** as shown below:

[image]

and added Api key in plist as shown :

[image]

With this integration now Crashlytics shows all the live devices count , App Store crashes with build versions and active users

Reference: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/examples/cannonball/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue and fixed this by modifying file permissions by executing following command in terminal:

```
chmod a+x Path/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-hhrnpfyhpluwgwcdjsjkbeehwwqs/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/Script-C0EDB4D81B6759AC0067631D.sh
chmod a+x ios_workspace/project/Pods/Fabric/run
chmod a+x ios_workspace/project/Pods/Fabric/uploadDSYM
```

> Note: Update path to `uploadDSYM`, `run` and `.sh` file accordingly

Answer (score 3):

This issue is caused by lack of access permission of the run file in Fabric.framework. You can find two files named `run` and `uploadDSYM` in the folder Fabric.framework of your project. Using terminal command below has solved my issue.

```
chmod 777 run
chmod 777 uploadDSYM
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
`chmod 777 YOUR_WORKSPACE_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

I you'll not lose code doing a kind of clean in your pods, you can do this

```
pod deintegrate
```

then:

```
pod install
```

After this your project should be just fine