# Shell Script Invocation Error with Fabric

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-fabric

I have installed Fabric and Crashlytics in my application using Cocoapods. I got an error while running the application and error message is given below.

Error :

> /project-path/Pods/Fabric/run: Permission denied

Comment: I think these are helpful - Please let me know if it's work -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407372/fabric-framework-run-permission-denied https://gist.github.com/Adnan1990/9a9eb45c6cebfb05fea0aa2376179571

Comment: I have tried this, but not working. I got  "Pods/Fabric/run: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed the issue and steps for the same is given below.

1. Open terminal and in your project go to the folder where fabric framework exist.if you are using pods then fabric will be inside pod folder (Command:- cd project-path/Pods).
2. Run below commands in terminal once you have reached the corresponding folder path.

   ```
   chmod +x Fabric/run 

   chmod +x Fabric/uploadDSYM
   ```

Run the below commands, once you have reached the root folder (Command:- cd ..)

```
    pod deintegrate 

    pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated shell script with pods root path with fabric key which will generated while installing fabric signup in build Phase as shown below:

Refer [Distribute Beta Builds](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/distribute-beta-builds.html) and [Distribute with iOS Build Tools](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html)

```
${SOURCE_ROOT}/Crashlytics.framework/submit <API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET>
```

[image]:

Comment: I have tried this, but failed.  Permission denied with Crashlytics