# Error Xcode 10 . PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code: errSecInternalComponent

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

> Showing Recent Messages :-1: Code Signing /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bszhnyuqdhgiqaaeosxrsxfkscut/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework
>   with Identity iPhone Developer: MyName (H837F7ABC3)
>
> :-1: /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign
>   59878098645E516950920B15DC30E4E94D7CADAD 
>   --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bszhnyuqdhgiqaaeosxrsxfkscut/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
>
> :-1:
>   /Users/marcel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceMe-bszhnyuqdhgiqaaeosxrsxfkscut/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/VoiceMe.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework:
>   errSecInternalComponent
>
> **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

I've installed the pods like 10 times ... cleaned and build the project not working also.

I'm running Xcode 10 and try to run it on a device.

Signing worked before just fine.

Comment: did you try put `${inherited}` in your `other linker flag` in build settings?

Comment: Yea did that now and not working either...

Comment: I'm stumped on the same error. What version of AlamoFire do you have installed?

Comment: The latest. Which I think it's 4.7.3

Comment: I have the same problem with firbase, after update to Xcode 10

Comment: This is happening when I try to run my project on new iPhone Max.  Huh.

Comment: Well, I have several projects and all throw the same error in Xcode 10 but with different frameworks. On Xcode 9.4 it's working fine.

Comment: hey guys. Suddenly it's working fine. No more errors. I've done so many things it's hard to say what solved my issue. but i generated the certificates 1 more time ( don't know if this solved the problem)

Comment: Seems similar issue resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649727/codesign-returned-errsecinternalcomponent-in-high-sierra/53552270#53552270

Answer (score 33):

I have facing the same issue, i believe this issue have something link to keychain access too (code signing problem), `I go to keychain access unlock the login then lock it again fixed this issue`. After uploading to`OSMojave` and Xcode 10 keychain need to reverify the password. (how i find this? while facing same issue and trying all available option, i think to generate certificate again, but while generating private key i found keychain login user name and password is wrong type of message- i lock and unlock again solved my problem). Note this process required your login pass phare.

Comment: This was insanely difficult to find an answer for.  Kudos for figuring this out!  Incidentally, this also fixes a different problem of not being able to send iMessage texts.

Comment: What do you mean "unlock the login" ?

Comment: in keychain, left side, top one is login  in keychain section. if it lock; unlock it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I just stumbled upon this issue with Xcode 11.3 and the only thing that worked was to completely remove Cocoa pods from the project and install it again from command line as [ChavirA suggested in this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52377044/2747762)

```html
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ pod install
```

hope it helps :D

Answer (score 1):

On errors like this (i.e. with no clear cause), I look at the error message detail to see if DerivedData is referenced as that can occasionally create issues even after you've cleaned the project (using Shift + Cmd + K).

Your error is referencing DerivedData (/Users/marcel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...) so the first thing I would do to troubleshoot would be to navigate to the DerivedData folder, find the respective project folder there and delete it. Then go back to Xcode and attempt to build the project.

Comment: tq this works for me. for me it's there was permission denied for Fabric. I found my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407372/fabric-framework-run-permission-denied

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal, navigate to the directory of your Xcode project and type:

```
pod update
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: There's no explanation as to what this is. On my system I get "command not found"

Comment: @MAH to use pod update you should have pods in your project. Make sure you do ,in case you don't this might not be the solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do lock/unlock keychain from terminal

```
sudo security lock-keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
sudo security unlock-keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```

Answer (score 0):

to fix that problem, you also can try "Try opening Keychain Access.app. Right-click on the login keychain and try locking it and then unlocking it again."

In my case, it's resolved my problem with codesign :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another team account in Signing section and run

After that you will see error , Then change it to your own account again and run

It will ask for your keychain password , Give the password and press "alway allow"

Then your good to go :)