# Cannot get Ionic 5 to deploy to physical device: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I am trying to deploy an Ionic 5 project to an iPhone 12 running iOS 14.6 with XCode 11.4. The app runs fine on the emulator but after following the official instructions [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios)  I get `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed` error and in the logs directly before that is this error:

```
Code Signing /Users/simonhill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-buuhfmnvjxqcivakwsfsgrdpsrjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework with Identity Apple Development: xxx@gmail.com (7FSK2UE87Y)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 7B0B8B04EB8EB60F0EB9540253FEC8FB09E379AC  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/simonhill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-buuhfmnvjxqcivakwsfsgrdpsrjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework'
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: simonhill303@gmail.com (7FSK2UE87Y)"
/Users/simonhill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-buuhfmnvjxqcivakwsfsgrdpsrjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework: errSecInternalComponent
```

I followed the instructions to create my Apple cert and don't understand how to fix this error. I tried this answer [Error Xcode 10 . PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code: errSecInternalComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499347/error-xcode-10-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-errsecint) but could not get it to work.

UPDATE
It may be this problem https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/:

> Known Issues Xcode 11.4.0 and earlier may not be able to sign software
> using signing certificates issued by the new Apple Worldwide Developer
> Relations Certification Intermediate Certificate. If you’re unable to
> upgrade to a supporting version of macOS or Xcode on your build
> machine, you can build and archive your app using an earlier Xcode
> client and sign it for distribution using the latest release.
> Alternatively, you can utilize the codesign tool to sign your software
> using the command line.

Definitely seems like this problem: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating XCode fixed the problem (12.4).