# git change permission failed to persist before next commit

Tags: linux, git

I need to set the permission of script.sh to `755`. So

```
git add -A
git update-index --chmod=+x script.sh
git commit -m 'first commit'
```

This way the file will be committed with a permission `755` and my remote vm can execute those scripts.

However, next time I do something to the repo and commit the changes the permission of those scripts will be reverted to `644`.  The message is

```
[master 171c0cc] second
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
 mode change 100755 => 100644 script.sh
```

Anyone know what might be happening here? How do I get rid of this?

Comment: update index doesn't change the permissions of the local file.  Just use normal unix chmod.

Answer (score 1):

First  check your [`git config core.fileMode`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config): if it is set to false, the executable bit of files in the working tree won't be honored anyway.

If it is true or not set, then [try a chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21419395/6309).

Then try also to [set `core.sharedRepository` to `group`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12735291/6309).
And check your umask. `umask 002` in your case should work.

Comment: right now `core.fileMode` is true. umask is 002.  I updated file mode to 755 and committed the changes.  But next time I do `git add -A` all the file modes changed back to 644.

Comment: Would core.shared repository (that I mentioned in the answer) would change anything?

Comment: I set `core.shareRepository` to `group` as you suggested but the results seem to be the same.

Comment: Make sure you have used core.sharedRepository, not share: shared

Comment: I think I know what's happening. I have to do `chmod 755` from the shell so future git commits will be based on the actual file mode.  Otherwise `git update-index --chmod=+x` is an one time thing and the file modes will revert back to 644 on next commit for some reason.