# What is the difference between "git add" and "git update-index"

Tags: git

What is the difference between "git add" and "git update-index"?

Under what circumstances would I use one of these commands or the other?

Answer (score 7):

Basically, `update-index` is a *plumbing* command - it means, low-level. `git add` internally uses `update-index`. I believe, that

`git add <file>` is the same as `git update-index --add <file>`

One of the circumstances, when I use update-index, is when you have a change to a file, which you don't want to commit - in this case you can run

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

So if you run `git status` after that, you'll see, that file not in the list of changed files.

More here [How to manage configuration files when collaborating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743770/git-collaboration-how-to-manage-configuration-files/4744071#4744071)

and here http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html

Answer (score 5):

To quote `git help update-index`:

> See also git-add(1) for a more user-friendly way to do some of the most common operations on the index.

So `git add` is the thing you normally use, while `git update-index` is the more powerful variant that also requires more knowledge on your side.

NB. It really pays off to get used to the `git help` command, the help pages of git are *excellent*.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is that `git add` would always use the current [index](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_index) named on-disk format version.

While [`git update-index --index-version`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---index-versionltngt) can write the resulting index out in a different format version.

Supported versions are 2, 3 and 4. The current default version is 2 or 3, depending on whether extra features are used, such as `git add -N`.

Version 4 performs a simple pathname compression that reduces index size by 30%-50% on large repositories, which results in faster load time. Git supports it since version 1.8.0, released in October 2012, and support for it was added to libgit2 in 2016 and to JGit in 2020.

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), "[`git update-index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3c2af826a35ecba8533748db5bd0a4dbda2d33db/Documentation/git-update-index.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index))</sup> learns `--show-index-version` to inspect the index format version used by the on-disk index file.

See [commit 83708f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83708f80fc5fc7202df0bf3c0951f85d31249fe3), [commit 606e088](https://github.com/git/git/commit/606e088d5d9af2393b4b05a8a180162c129cd734), [commit 764b233](https://github.com/git/git/commit/764b2330db42d07ed8c7d4f6c66a1d1203fb95de) (12 Sep 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3c2af82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c2af826a35ecba8533748db5bd0a4dbda2d33db), 20 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`update-index`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/606e088d5d9af2393b4b05a8a180162c129cd734): add --show-index-version
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Linus Arver</sup>

> "[`git update-index --index-version N`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/606e088d5d9af2393b4b05a8a180162c129cd734/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L161)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---index-versionltngt))</sup> is used to set the index format version to a specific version, but there was no way to query the current version used in the on-disk index file.
>
> Teach the command a new "`--show-index-version`" option, and also teach the "`--index-version N`" option to report what the version was when run with the "`--verbose`" option.

`git update-index` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/606e088d5d9af2393b4b05a8a180162c129cd734/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L175-L177):

> ### `--show-index-version`
>
> Report the index format version used by the on-disk index file.
> See `--index-version` above.