# Git - submodule dirty - Visual Studio project file

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio project with two solutions. One is my current project, the other one is a submodule. Entire project is in git. I have used gitignore generated by Visual Studio for the project.

Part of the submodule is also Visual Studio solution and project settings for the submodule project. I have added this submodule to my solution but I needed to change include directories and active build fot he submodule.

If I want to commit my project, git is complaining about submodule being "dirty" and I can commit submodule or ignore it. I want to commit submodule only if source codes have changed. Is there any way how to stop git complaining about "dirty" submodule, or I have to do "ignore" every time I commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I needed to change include directories and active build fot he submodule.

So that is why the main parent repository considers its submodule "dirty": there are pending changes in it.

If said changes are purely local to your workstation, you might consider remove them from the index consideration with [`git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38586472/6309):

```
 cd /path/to/submodule
 git reset -- modified/file
 git update-index --assume-unchanged -- modified/file
```

That is a local workaround, to make sure those files don't show up as modified in the submodule status.